# Really don't get why my array doesn't sort ascending but descending

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I'm a newbie. Don't really get why it's in descending order and not ascending, since I check each element of array with all other elements and if the former is greater, it becomes the latter, and so on, so the element should go slowly right in the order, but what happens is the opposite.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void){
    unsigned int array[7] = {3,1,6,9,0,44,4};

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<=6; ++i){
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<=6; ++j){
            if (array[i] > array[j]){
                int hold = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i];
                array[i] = hold;
            }
        }
    }
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<=6; ++i){
        printf("%4d", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
  44   9   6   4   3   1
```

I know that replacing ">" with "<" I have it in ascendent order, but I don't get why.

Edit: following the answers I received, if I replace (in the inner loop) that 0 with "i+1", it works. I'm gonna try to understand better why.

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between `>` and `<`?

Comment: The inner loop should be `for (unsigned int j=i+1; j<=6; ++j)` . Once the i'th element has been positioned, it should not be touched again. Your incorrect 0-based inner loop is having the later `array[i]` elements comparing against lower `array[j]` elements that in reality have already been sorted.

Comment: @WhozCraig but why if I write j=i and not j=i+1 it works the same?

Comment: *Think*.. about what `j=i` does differently. Will `array[n] < array[n]` *ever* be true (which is exactly what you have when `i` and `j` are ever equal, which they are when `j=i` is the initial starting point)?? No, it won't be, so the first iteration of the inner loop starting at `j=i` would always be a no-op, never perform a swap, and therefore utterly pointless. Thus why `j=i+i` is the proper starting point for the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have attempted to implement a [Selection Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).  The code is mostly right, but there is a logical flaw in the way you have structured your loops, and in particular in the range covered by your inner loop.  Run your code in a debugger to see what's going on, or try to explain in detail to your rubber duck / pet dog / computer mouse what the code is doing and why.